# CSS file linking issue

Tags: html, css, file, file-link

Why is my CSS file not linked when the HTML file is inside a folder within the folder that contains both folders?
I tried deleting the main folder address from the link and it still persists.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1mWA.jpg

*The CSS file is OK and works only when the HTML file is not in a separate folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the relative path to the CSS file, then the link href needs to be relative to your html file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/9a.css">`

The `..` indicates that you want to navigate outside the "html" folder where your html file is located, then find the "css" folder, then find your css file.